# How to get the Average on a count of grouped rows

Tags: sql, sqlite

In a single table I'm trying to group records on a column, count the total results in each group, and then get the average of the counts:

```
SELECT AVG(cnt) FROM 
   (SELECT COUNT(*) AS 'cnt'
   FROM birds
   GROUP BY birdID
);
```

So the table might look like:

```
birdID
------ 
Robin 
Robin 
Robin 
BlueJay 
BlueJay 
BlueJay 
Falcon
```

The counts for each:

```
Robin - 3
BlueJay - 3
Falcon - 1
```

And the overall average is 3 + 3 + 1 = 7 / 3 (total groups) = 2.3

My nested query works fine. But it seems like it could be done with one query, and not two.

AVG(COUNT(*)) doesn't work, though that's kinda what I'm trying to get at.

Sql returns the error 'misuse of aggregate function COUNT()' when using AVG(COUNT(*))

Comment: "it seems like it could be done with one query, and not two." it can't, unless you use a windowed `AVG(COUNT(*)) OVER ()`, in which case you get 3 rows the same, and it's less efficient. What you have is correct (note that other database systems require the count to be casted to decimal first).

Answer (score 2):

This should do the job...

```sql
SELECT ROUND(AVG(CNT), 2) AS "AVERAGE_COUNT_OF_IDS"
FROM (
    SELECT BIRD_ID, COUNT(*) AS "CNT"
    FROM tbl
    GROUP BY BIRD_ID
);
/*    R e s u l t :
AVERAGE_COUNT_OF_IDS
--------------------
2.33                  */
```

... see it here https://sqlfiddle.com/sqlite/online-compiler?id=9be29b9c-3f57-49c8-afaa-5aeb598e3bc2

If you want it without subquery then try this:

```sql
--  transform counts to decimal values
Select Round( Round(COUNT(*), 2) / Round(COUNT(DISTINCT BIRD_ID), 2), 2) AS "AVG_CNT"
From tbl;
/*    R e s u l t :
AVG_CNT
---------
2.33      */
```

... see it here https://sqlfiddle.com/sqlite/online-compiler?id=9c5fb9ac-9631-4638-b0e6-6ccaaa37bc00

Comment: That's the same as OP, apart from the rounding, which because it's odne on the outside is immaterial.

Comment: @Charlieface I agree, but with a small difference - this for some reason works (see fiddle). We don't know OP's context which makes it hard to tell what is the problem there.

Comment: But so does OP's https://sqlfiddle.com/sqlite/online-compiler?id=9be29b9c-3f57-49c8-afaa-5aeb598e3bc2

Comment: @Charlieface I agree again. Conclusion: OP's context (unknown to us) - something else causes the error.

Comment: Adding a second output to the fiddle: SELECT AVG(COUNT(*)) AS '2nd avg' FROM tbl GROUP BY BIRD_ID;  doesn't produce output. It's likely an error like I had originally. It seems a nested query is necessary.

Comment: @ScottAlanTurner Just posted the code without subquery...